# how can i bind different user controlls depending on a user selection in the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

hey i am using wpf and mvvm. i have a normal wpf window where I assigned a certain view model to the `DataContext`. there is a `Combobox` in the window. in the setter of the `Combobox` i want to change the content of a certain area of the `Window`. so there are 5 options in the `Combobox`and i created 5 different `UserControl` instances that are corresponding to the options. how can i change the `UserControl` via binding?
because until now i included a `UserControl` via `<local:MYUSERCONTROLL datacontext= UsercontrollVM>` 
so in my general view model i can for change the UserControl-ViewModel by assigning UsercontrollVM with a new Value. but if i do not only want to change the View Model but the VIew Itself - the `UserControl` - how do i do it? 
Like the `<locl:MYUSERCONTROLL>` i dont see how to connect a binding there as its kind of hard coded already....

can someone help me?

the solution i will choose if no one has a clue: i will put in the XAML all 5 different `UserControl` elements and then put a `Visibility={Binding Option1}` and then only show the Option that is selected in the `Combobox`, but it seems very ugly to do it like that!

Comment: Well, you could work with triggers. But there might be something better then User Controls: Type Targetting Data Templates. A Data Template that targets a specific VIewModel class and depending wich one you expose, a different tempalte would be picked.

Comment: Bind combobox to collection of view models and use data templates to display selected in combobox view model as view.

Comment: Of coruse it could also be that this is a case for register cards, rather then a combo box.

Comment: Is your Shift key broken?

Comment: You should take a look at templates. You typically use a `DataTemplate` to describe the visual appearance of a `Control` based on the data type. You then can simply switch the data type of the data source in your view model or let the user do it by selecting a different type. If the data type is the same you can define multiple `DataTemplate` and use a `DataTemplateSelector` to switch in and out the appropriate `DataTemplate`.

Comment: [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=netframework-4.8#examples) and [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=netframework-4.8#examples).

Comment: So instead of 5 different `UserControl` classes you should consider to have 5 templates e.g. for a `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: How different are each of the user controls? Do they all require 5 separate ViewModels?

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo project for a colleague that does something similar and should get you on track. There are 2 different ways I have done this.

**1:** Simple solution. View making changes to a view.

Below I have a `Grid` with a control inside.

```
        <Grid x:Name="grid1">
            <local:UserControl1 x:Name="usercontrol1Content"/>
        </Grid>
```

In the code behind, I have a button click event that changes the user control. I only created this as a quick test but you might need to manually release resources if they are in use if there is an existing control in place before removing. I have not really tested this too much since it was just a proof of concept.

```
    private void changeControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add check to see if the existing view is already being displayed so we do not try to add load it again.
        grid1.Children.Clear();
        UIElement uIElement = new UserControl3();
        grid1.Children.Add(uIElement);
    }
```

**2:** Less simple. Use a `ContentPresenter` and `DataTemplate`.

Same grid as above but with the added stuff.

```
    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="usercontrol1Template" DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl1ViewModel}">
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Name="usercontrol2Template" DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl2ViewModel}">
                <local:UserControl2/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Changing of the control can be done from either code behind or inside a window ViewModel if you bind things correctly. I will show the simple code behind stuff below.

```
    private void changeControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl2 userControl2 = new UserControl2();
        grid1.DataContext = new UserControl2ViewModel();
    }
```

There are other ways to do this, but these are the most simple and should get you started.